# Nonlinear differential equation, separation of variables, is it correct?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could you tell me what method I could use to solve this differential equation?

$$x'=x^3-x^2+x$$

Will separation of variables work here?

$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = x^3(t) - x^2(t) + x(t)$$

So it would seem that we need to solve $$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{x^3(t) - x^2(t) + x(t)} = \int \text{d}t$$

Is it correct?

Comment: on the left hand side of your last equation,  there is no need for showing the functional  dependence by writing $x(t).$ it needs to be plain $x.$ the dependence, constraint between $t$ and $x$ is what the equation determines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. You should rather write
$$
\int \frac{1}{x(t)^3-x(t)^2+x(t)}x'(t)\, dt = \int dt
$$
or
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^3-x^2+x}\, dx = \int dt \tag{1}
$$
It might look as a pedantic remark, but you should understand what you are doing. Anyway you can now compute the integrals in (1) and find your solution, at least in the form $t=t(x)$.